# Replace a line in a file with portions of that line

Tags: sed

I got a list of installed programs on my ubuntu box using `apt list --installed`

Here is a snippet of the list

```
wdiff/xenial,now 1.2.2-1build1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
wget/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 1.17.1-1ubuntu1.5 amd64 [installed]
whiptail/xenial,now 0.52.18-1ubuntu2 amd64 [installed]
xauth/xenial,now 1:1.0.9-1ubuntu2 amd64 [installed]
xdg-user-dirs/xenial-updates,now 0.15-2ubuntu6.16.04.1 amd64 [installed]
xfsprogs/xenial-updates,now 4.3.0+nmu1ubuntu1.1 amd64 [installed]
xkb-data/xenial,now 2.16-1ubuntu1 all [installed]
```

I need the program name and version. 
For example:
`wdiff/xenial,now 1.2.2-1build1 amd64 [installed,automatic]` 
becomes
`wdiff    1.2.2-1build1`

I devised this command which works.

```
apt list --installed  | sed -r 's@/@ @g' | awk '{print $1 "\t" $3}'  | sort -u
```

I'd like to know how to use only sed to make a new file with portions of the input file line.

This regex:
`^([^\/]+)\/[^\s]+\s([^\s]+)`

- Capture from start of line to the first /
- Ignore to the first whitespace
- Capture after the first whitespace to the second whitespace

And I should be able to use sed backreferences to the capture groups and build the new output.

`apt list --installed | sed -r 's/^([^\/]+)\/[^\s]+\s([^\s]+)/\1    \2/'`

However it seems the output doesn't match my expectation.

```
wdiff   [installed,automatic]
wget/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 1.17.1-1ubuntu1.5 amd64 [installed]
whiptail    [installed]
xauth   [installed]
xdg-user-dirs/xenial-updates,now 0.15-2ubuntu6.16.04.1 amd64 [installed]
xfsprogs/xenial-updates,now 4.3.0+nmu1ubuntu1.1 amd64 [installed]
xkb-data    [installed]
```

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

What is going wrong? You captured the wrong group and you didn't discard to the end of input string after the last match you wanted to keep, only to the next non-whitepace

```
sed -r 's/^([^\/]+)\/[^\s]+\s([^\s]+)/\1    \2/'

([^/]+)   #capture everything up to /, OK
/         #discard the /. OK
[^\s]     #discard the next non white-space group, this is the bit you actually want
\s        #discard the whitespace
([^\s]+)  #capture the next non-whitespace group
#leave anything after the last non-whitespace found
```

You probably ended up doing this because of the poor readability with all of the escapes. If you clean it up it will help you debug

```
sed -E 's|([^/]*)[^ ]* +([^ ]*).*|\1 \2|' infile | column -t

([^/]*)    #capture up to the /
[^ ]* +    #discard until the space and any spaces
([^ ])     #capture the next character group until a space
.*         #discard to the end of the string
```

Unless you have specified a global match (`s///g`) you dont need the `^` anchor.

Use `|` as a separator to avoid the unnecessary escapes on your matching string

The `column -t` does a better job of alignment than multiple spaces

Answer (score 0):

Try the following (unoptimized) regex:

```
$ sed 's/\(^.*\)\(\/[^ ]* \)\([^ ]* \)\([^ ]* \)\([^ ]*\)/\1 \3/' infile
wdiff 1.2.2-1build1 
wget 1.17.1-1ubuntu1.5 
whiptail 0.52.18-1ubuntu2 
xauth 1:1.0.9-1ubuntu2 
xdg-user-dirs 0.15-2ubuntu6.16.04.1 
xfsprogs 4.3.0+nmu1ubuntu1.1 
xkb-data 2.16-1ubuntu1
```